# Opto / MOSFET switching question

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator

UPDATE: To reflect evildemonic's comment.

[image]

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I have this circuit.

[image]

The goal is to be able to put different high voltage rails into the circuit with this 3 pin screw down connector. For example I am going to put 12 V in on pin 1 on HV1. I am then going to be able to switch this load for this lamp using the opto-isolator and the MOSFET.

I think that pin 1 and 2 have to be connected together. If the MOSFET starts conducting there is not voltage on the load line to pull current through to the source. Is this right?

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment:  thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep everything how you have it, except disconnect Pin 3 from ground and instead attach it to the 12 V instead.  You want the load to ground through the N-MOSFET.

How you have it now, when the MOSFET is conducting, both sides of the load are grounded.

If you connect pins 1 and 2 together, when you activate the MOSFET it will short the 12 V to ground.  Don't do that.

Comment: And put a resistor in series with the opto-isolator's LED

Comment: @evildemonic thanks for the suggestion.  I updated the image with your improvements.  However, I think I need to use this 4 pin connector right?  I am need to provide the power ground for the rail as well. Since the switching logic is meant to be isolated from the power circuit.   Does this sound/look right?

Comment: @ril3y Yes, well done.  Don't forget to add the current limiting resistor Simon Fitch pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend these changes: -

[image]

If HV1GND needs to be connected somewhere then use a 4 pin header for HV1.

Comment: Thanks Andy,  I figured out the 4 pin connector too!  I think my updated picture is basically what you recommended just choose different pins.  When you say a more powerful device you mean a diode that can handle more reverse current?  Do you have a good example part?  Also it looks like this 817 is at 100% 5ma @5v.  I am providing 3v3 for the source switch voltage.  So 300ohms should limit 3v3 to 5ma.  Does that sound right?

Comment: My diagram repositions the diode to a more effective and useful position. More powerful means more **forward** current; it's the forward conduction that prevents stray inductance creating a big splash of back-emf. Yes, 300 ohms sounds about right.